# How run a java jar with a customize name or id in the cmd?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

Hi guys I 'm running a jar like:
`javaw -jar program.jar` 
after that in my windows process i will have a process with the name Java(TM) Platform SE binary...
[image]

My question is if exist the way to run this jar with a name or id and in the windows process have a customize name like MyProgram instead of Java(TM) Platform SE.
Please can anyone help me with this issue?
Regards

Comment: Thank you but I want to put the name in the same sentence in the command line like java - jar myprogram.jar -name name
something like this

Comment: Well i found that my issue is a Oracle's issue you can see here https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6299778